# why would a xsl:template match not be processed?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FDT xmlns="x-schema:FDTMISPScanIdentSchema.xml" xmlns:mispident="x-schema:FDTMISPIdentSchema.xml"
    xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml">
    <ScanIdentifications fdt:busCategory="D5FABA0D-8EE1-4AD0-8D2F-9B2D052C10C4"
        resultState="final">
        <ScanIdentification>
            <IdBusProtocol mispident:busProtocol="MISP" />
            <IdBusProtocolVersion
                mispident:mispRevisionLevel="1" />
            <IdManufacturer
                mispident:manufacturerIdentificationCode="32" />
            <IdAddress mispident:address="9600N81" />
            <IdTypeID mispident:deviceTypeCode="60" />
            <IdSerialNumber mispident:serial="0" />
            <IdSoftwareRevision mispident:softwareRevision="1.0.4" />
            <IdHardwareRevision />
        </ScanIdentification>
    </ScanIdentifications>
</FDT>
```

I'm using this XSLT to transform the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
FDT: device identification transformation for MISP device identification xml files
-->
<xsl:transform  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string"
        xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
        xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml"
        xmlns:scanident="x-schema:DTMScanIdentSchema.xml"
        xmlns:devident="x-schema:DTMDeviceTypeIdentSchema.xml"
        xmlns:mispident="x-schema:FDTMISPIdentSchema.xml"
        xmlns:mispdevice="x-schema:FDTMISPDeviceTypeIdentSchema.xml"
        xmlns:mispscan="x-schema:FDTMISPScanIdentSchema.xml" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <!--
FDT: version of this file
    -->

    <xsl:variable name="FileVersion">
        <xsl:number value="1.0"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!--
root: transform device or scan identification
-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//mispscan:ScanIdentifications"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//mispdevice:DeviceIdentifications"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MISP identification list
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:DeviceIdentifications">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
    &lt;!-- This file is created by FDTMISPIdentTransformation.xsl after transformation of MISPDTMDeviceIdentificationInstance.xml --&gt;
    &lt;FDT xmlns="x-schema:DTMDeviceTypeIdentSchema.xml"
     xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml" xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml" &gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:element name="DeviceIdentifications">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:DeviceIdentification"/>
                </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/FDT&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MISP catalog identifcation
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:DeviceIdentification">
            <xsl:element name="DeviceIdentification">
                <xsl:attribute name="ident:idDTMSupportLevel">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:idDTMSupportLevel"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdBusProtocol"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdBusProtocolVersion"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdManufacturer"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdTypeID"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdSoftwareRevision"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:IdHardwareRevision"/>
                <xsl:element name="IdValues">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:DeviceCommandRevisionLevel"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:DeviceFlag"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispdevice:ManufacturerSpecificExtension"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MISP scan list
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:ScanIdentifications">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
    &lt;!-- This file is created by FDTMISPIdentTransformation.xsl after transformation of MISPDTMScanIdentificationInstance.xml --&gt;&lt;FDT xmlns="x-schema:DTMScanIdentSchema.xml"
     xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml" xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml" &gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:element name="ScanIdentifications">
                    <xsl:attribute name="fdt:busCategory">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@fdt:busCategory"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="resultState">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@resultState"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:ScanIdentification"/>
                </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/FDT&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>


<!--
MISP scan identifcation
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:ScanIdentification">
            <xsl:element name="ScanIdentification">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@configuredState" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fdt:CommunicationError"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdBusProtocol"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdBusProtocolVersion"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdAddress"/>          
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdManufacturer"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdTypeID"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdSoftwareRevision"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdHardwareRevision"/>
                <!-- don't get why this particular template doesn't work -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdTag"/>
                <!--  
                <xsl:element name="IdDeviceTag">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Tag</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdSerialNumber"/>
                <xsl:element name="IdValues">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:DeviceCommandRevisionLevel"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:DeviceFlag"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:ManufacturerSpecificExtension"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
configured attribute
-->
    <xsl:template match="@configuredState">
        <xsl:attribute name="configuredState">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
MispScanIdentification: device tag, just copy
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdTag">
        <xsl:element name="IdDeviceTag">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Tag</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MispScanIdentification: communicationError
-->
    <xsl:template match="fdt:CommunicationError">
        <xsl:element name="fdt:CommunicationError">
            <xsl:attribute name="communicationError"><xsl:value-of select="@communicationError"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="tag"><xsl:value-of select="@tag"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MispScanIdentification: serialnumber
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdSerialNumber">
        <xsl:element name="IdSerialNumber">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"><xsl:value-of select="@mispident:serial"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Device Identification Number</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MispScanIdentification: busaddress, just copy
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdAddress">
        <xsl:element name="IdAddress">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"><xsl:value-of select="@mispident:address"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Port Configuration</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
MispScanIdentification: CommandRevision, saved as protocol specific value
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:DeviceCommandRevisionLevel">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:deviceCommandRevisionLevel"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">DeviceCommandRevisionLevel</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Device Revision Level</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:DeviceCommandRevisionLevel">
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">DeviceCommandRevisionLevel</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:deviceCommandRevisionLevel"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Device Revision Level</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MispScanIdentification: DeviceFlag, saved as protocol specific value
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:DeviceFlag">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:deviceFlag"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">DeviceFlag</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Flags</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:DeviceFlag">
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">DeviceFlag</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:deviceFlag"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Flags</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
Misp Manufacaturer
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdManufacturer">
        <xsl:param name="manid" select="@mispident:manufacturerIdentificationCode"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdManufacturer">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$manid"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Manufacturer Identification Code</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdManufacturer">
        <xsl:element name="IdManufacturer">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:manufacturerIdentificationCode"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Manufacturer Identification Code</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
DevId:IdBusProtocol
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdBusProtocol">
        <xsl:param name="manid" select="@mispident:busProtocol"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdBusProtocol">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$manid"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">MISP</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdBusProtocol">
        <xsl:element name="IdBusProtocol">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:busProtocol"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">MISP</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
DevId:IdBusProtocolVersion
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdBusProtocolVersion">
        <xsl:param name="manid" select="@mispident:mispRevisionLevel"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdBusProtocolVersion">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$manid"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">MISP Revision</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdBusProtocolVersion">
        <xsl:element name="IdBusProtocolVersion">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:mispRevisionLevel"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">MISP Revision</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
MISP device type
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdTypeID">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:deviceTypeCode"/>
        <xsl:param name="value_alt" select="@mispident:deviceTypeId"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdTypeID">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatchChoose">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="value_alt" select="$value_alt"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Device Type Code</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdTypeID">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:deviceTypeCode"/>
        <xsl:param name="value_alt" select="@mispident:deviceTypeId"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdTypeID">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatchChoose">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="value_alt" select="$value_alt"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Device Type Code</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
MISP software revision
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdSoftwareRevision">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:softwareRevision"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdSoftwareRevision">
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Software Revision</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdSoftwareRevision">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:softwareRevision"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdSoftwareRevision">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Software Revision</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
MISP hardware revision
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:IdHardwareRevision">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:hardwareRevision"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdHardwareRevision">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Hardware Revision</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:IdHardwareRevision">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:hardwareRevision"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdHardwareRevision">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Hardware Revision</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<!--
ManufacturerSpecificExtension
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispdevice:ManufacturerSpecificExtension">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="@mispident:manufacturerSpecificExtension"/>
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">ManufacturerSpecificExtension</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="genMatch">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">ManufacturerSpecificExtension</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mispscan:ManufacturerSpecificExtension">
        <xsl:element name="IdValue">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:name">ManufacturerSpecificExtension</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mispident:manufacturerSpecificExtension"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">ManufacturerSpecificExtension</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


<!--
generate matching information
-->
    <xsl:template name="genMatch">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="empty"/>
        <xsl:if test="$value!=$empty">
            <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mispident:RegExpr"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
generate matching information by selecting one from two possible choices
-->
    <xsl:template name="genMatchChoose">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="value_alt"/>
        <xsl:param name="empty"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$value!=$empty">
                <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$value_alt!=$empty">
                <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"><xsl:value-of select="$value_alt"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mispident:RegExpr"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
generate regular exressions
-->
    <xsl:template match="mispident:RegExpr">
        <!-- copy pattern info -->
        <xsl:call-template name="genPattern">
            <xsl:with-param name="match" select="@match"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nomatch" select="@nomatch"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
<!--
generate pattern information
-->
    <xsl:template name="genPattern">
        <xsl:param name="match"/>
        <xsl:param name="nomatch"/>
        <xsl:param name="empty"/>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match!=$empty">
            <xsl:element name="ident:RegExpr">
                <xsl:attribute name="match"><xsl:value-of select="$match"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="$nomatch!=$empty">
                    <xsl:attribute name="nomatch"><xsl:value-of select="$nomatch"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$nomatch!=$empty">
            <xsl:element name="ident:RegExpr">
                <xsl:attribute name="nomatch"><xsl:value-of select="$nomatch"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="$match!=$empty">
                    <xsl:attribute name="match"><xsl:value-of select="$match"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This file is created by FDTMISPIdentTransformation.xsl after transformation 
    of MISPDTMScanIdentificationInstance.xml -->
<FDT xmlns="x-schema:DTMScanIdentSchema.xml" xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
    xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml">
    <ScanIdentifications xmlns:fdt="x-schema:FDTDataTypesSchema.xml"
        fdt:busCategory="D5FABA0D-8EE1-4AD0-8D2F-9B2D052C10C4" resultState="final">
        <ScanIdentification>
            <IdBusProtocol xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="MISP" ident:protocolSpecificName="MISP" />
            <IdBusProtocolVersion xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="1" ident:protocolSpecificName="MISP Revision" />
            <IdAddress xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="9600N81" ident:protocolSpecificName="Port Configuration" />
            <IdManufacturer xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="32" ident:protocolSpecificName="Manufacturer Identification Code" />
            <IdTypeID xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="60" ident:protocolSpecificName="Device Type Code" />
            <IdSoftwareRevision xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:protocolSpecificName="Software Revision" ident:value="1.0.4" />
            <IdHardwareRevision xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:protocolSpecificName="Hardware Revision" />
            <IdSerialNumber xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml"
                ident:value="0" ident:protocolSpecificName="Device Identification Number" />
            <IdValues />
        </ScanIdentification>
    </ScanIdentifications>
</FDT>
```

What I don't understand is why the xsl:apply-templates match for mispscan:IdTag isn't being processed.  I expect a element after IdHardwareRevision like so:

```
<IdDeviceTag xmlns:ident="x-schema:DTMIdentSchema.xml" ident:value="" ident:protocolSpecificName="Tag"/>
```

Is it because the template:

```
<xsl:template match="mispscan:IdTag">
    <xsl:element name="IdDeviceTag">
        <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Tag</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

doesn't have any match tests for the source document or something like that?  I note that if I just generate the element in the mispscan:ScanIdentification template like so

```
<xsl:template match="mispscan:ScanIdentification">
        <xsl:element name="ScanIdentification">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@configuredState" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fdt:CommunicationError"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdBusProtocol"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdBusProtocolVersion"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdAddress"/>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdManufacturer"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdTypeID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdSoftwareRevision"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdHardwareRevision"/>
            <!-- don't get why this particular template doesn't work 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdTag"/>
            -->
            <xsl:element name="IdDeviceTag">
                <xsl:attribute name="ident:value"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="ident:protocolSpecificName">Tag</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:IdSerialNumber"/>
            <xsl:element name="IdValues">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:DeviceCommandRevisionLevel"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:DeviceFlag"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="mispscan:ManufacturerSpecificExtension"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It works the way I expect.

I guess this is fine, but I'd like to know exactly why the mispscan:IdTag template did not get processed.

Comment: Why do you write `<xsl:element name="IdDeviceTag">` when you could write `<IdDeviceTag>` and `<xsl:attribute name="communicationError"><xsl:value-of select="@communicationError"/></xsl:attribute>` when you could write `<IdDeviceTag communicationError="{@communicationError}">`? Your code is *way* too verbose, even for XSLT.

Comment: XML seems excessively verbose to me so I didn't really notice. :)  @Tomalak, I don't work with XSLT very much, so I didn't know that you could do what you suggested.  This XSLT is a modified version of another one that I picked up.  Verbose, yeah, but I didn't type most of it.

Comment: The amount of needless duplication in this XSLT file is excessive. Also the file seems want to create two separate XML files. Is that the case?

Comment: Also, there is no `mispscan:IdTag` in the input, why would you expect one to be the output?`

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem, apparently.  Also, the transform only generates one xml file, but is able to process two different input schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are several reasons why a template that matches particular elements might not be evaluated:

- No xsl:apply-templates in the stylesheet ever causes template matching to occur on the element in question.  In many stylesheets written in conventional XSLT style, this boils down to:  the template that matched the parent element didn't include any xsl:apply-templates instruction.
- There is another template with higher priority that matches the element in question.
- There is no element in the input that matches the template.

Since there is no mispscan:IdTag element in the input you show, it looks as if the cause in this case is the third one:  your template for mispscan:IdTag isn't being evaluated because it doesn't match anything in the input.

Comment: Yes, apparently this is the sticking point in my understanding.  I had thought that the template matching occurred in the xml itself after a input element was selected.  This is incorrect.  Template matches always occur with the input.  If the input matches, the corresponding template in the xsl is processed.  Hmm, so obvious...